# Filter a list of files by content

Tags: files, macos, filter

I got a command `foo` that outputs a list of files separated by a new line.

How can I filter those files by their content using regex, and output the filtered files list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your system has GNU `xargs`, you could do something like

```
foo | xargs -d '\n' grep -l regex
```

Comment: It's not working for me, I am getting: `xargs: illegal option -- d`. I am using Mac OS

Comment: @IlyaGazman unfortunately I am not familiar with the OSX version of xargs

Comment: Is the `-d` necessary? `xargs` should use newlines by default, right?

Comment: @terdon That won't work if the filenames contain whitespace. Maybe use a workaround like `foo | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 grep -l 'regex'`?

Comment: @Freddy ah yes, the `-d` is needed for whitespace yes.

Comment: it works for me if I omit the `-d`, didn't tested for white spaces.

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`:

```
foo |
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        grep -qE "$regex" "$file" && printf '%s\n' "$file"
    done
```

If your `grep` does not understand `-q` then you can use

```
grep -E "$regex" "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

instead.