# How to limit grep to scan only the first 10 lines?

Tags: files, grep, macos, filter

I got a command `foo` that output a list of files separated by `\n` line.

I am using the below command to filter the results by regex content of the files.

```
foo | xargs grep -l regex
```

The problem is that some files are very large and the content that I am searching can be found only at the first 10 lines. How can I tell grep to only process the first 10 lines in order to speed this execution?

Comment: I'd suggest using [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597776/65304) to your earlier question, which can be straightforwardly modified to include a `head` command

Comment: You can use grep option `-m 1` which stops reading the file after the first match. Doesn't help with big files if the pattern is not found.

Comment: @glennjackman doesn't the `-l` option stop after the first match anyhow?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, but I didn't want to assume the OP only wanted a list of matching filenames.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah, I agree. `-m 1` is a good solution, but it only solves half of the problem.

Comment: @IlyaGazman do you just want the matching file name printed or the matching line? If just the file name then `-l` is the correct argument, if the full line then `-m 1`. Either is easy to do but you need to tell us which you want.

Comment: @EdMorton print the file names

Answer (score 1):

As commented, to solve half the problem:

```bsh
foo | xargs grep -m 1 regex
```

To solve the rest requires a bit more scripting:

```bsh
foo | xargs sh -c 'for file; do head "$file"; done | grep regex' sh
```

But that doesn't give you the filenames because grep is reading a stream.

If you have GNU awk:

```bsh
foo | xargs gawk -v pattern='regex' -v lines=10 -v OFS=':' '
  $0 ~ pattern {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}
  FNR == lines {nextfile}
'
```

To just get the filename

```c
  $0 ~ pattern {print FILENAME; nextfile}
```

Comment: I see you've tagged [tag:macos]: you can get GNU awk with `brew install gawk`

Comment: You should probably add a `nextfile` after the `print` too in case the "pattern" appears multiple times in the first 10 lines since the OP seems to just want the file names and even if not then that'd mimic what `grep -m 1` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(foo); do echo -e "$i \c"; head -n10 $i | grep -c regex; done
```

will print the filenames from the `foo` script followed by a number. If the number is zero, then no `regex` match, and these zero entries in the result can easily be filtered out if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of [glenn jackman's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597822/332764) that outputs the filenames:

```
foo | xargs sh -c 'for file; do head "$file" | grep -l --label="$file" regex; done' sh
```